# Grails can't find classes in jars

Tags: grails, jar

I have an app in Grails that uses a .java to manage paypal MassPay feature. Like many .java, it needs some jars that enclose the classes that jar uses. Ok, i import that jars and the errors in the .java dissapears. But now, when I try to run the app, i receive 25 messages like this:

```
myapproute/grails-app/controllers/com/mycompany/widget/MassPay.java:3: package com.paypal.sdk.profiles does not exist
import com.paypal.sdk.profiles.APIProfile;
```

That file in the MassPay.java does not throw any error, since i imported the jar where that class is enclosed. But it doesn't allow me to run the project.

Any help? thanks.

Im using Eclipse, not NetBeans (i have read that there is a bug in Netbeans)

Answer (score 5):

Adding JARs to the Eclipse project build path is not sufficient to make them visible to Grails.  You need to either put them in the application's `lib` directory and run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` or (better) if the JARs are available in a Maven-compatible repository simply [declare your dependencies in `BuildConfig.groovy`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#ivy) and let Grails download the JARs itself.

Comment: I already tried to copy the files in the lib directory and says "Cannot paste the clipboard content into the selected element". And the files are .jar!

Comment: That sounds like an Eclipse problem rather than a Grails one, can you copy the JAR files into the right place outside of Eclipse (using Explorer/Finder/whatever the file manager is called on your platform)?  You'll need to "refresh" the Eclipse project for it to see the new files.

Comment: Trying now... Ill tell you how it ends.

Comment: Nah, copied, typed the command you said (wich is never completed because of an error ill paste in another comment, too big for this) and i keep having the same errors when i try to run the project.

Comment: Error Error executing script Grails: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2$RootHandler.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelper2$RootHandler, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type org/xml/sax/Locator used in the signature (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: Which JARs precisely are you trying to add to `lib`?  You should leave out things like `xml-apis` and `stax-api` because the classes they contain are already available by default in Java 6, and adding them will cause the kind of errors you're seeing.

Comment: You want a full list? https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_java_windows__soap_sdk.zip this is the zip i downloaded from paypal site. Inside there is a "lib" folder where the jars are.

Comment: Of those, I suspect `xerces`, `xercesImpl`, `activation`, `log4j` and `saaj` can probably be removed.  `xerces` is likely to be the one causing the particular error you've seen but the others will probably cause similar errors later on...  However this SDK is based on a very old version of Apache Axis and I'm not sure it'll work at all in combination with the more recent libraries required by grails.  Is there any way you can use the "new PayPal SDK" instead (https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#expresscheckoutnew)?

Comment: I deleted the ones you said, but keeps throwing the same error, but now it yells when the project is run, not when I type the command you said. Speaking of the Apache Axis, im not using it (already deleted), im only using paypal_base.jar and paypal_stubs.jar, I get off my workspace all the other jars, leaving only these two. Still, same problem.

Comment: Then the offending class must be inside one of the jars you have left.  It looks unlikely that it'll be possible to get this working in Grails, so I strongly suggest you look at the newer SDK that doesn't have these kinds of external dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for all your time and your help, Ian :)

Answer (score -1):

Run this - it will work

```
grails clean
```